# Nondecreasing function

Tags: calculus, functions

$a)$ Let $f(x)=x−1−\ln x$. Show that $f$ is nondecreasing on $[1,\infty)$.

$b)$ Use the result from $(a)$ to show that

$$\ln x ≤ x-1\text{ when }x ≥ 1.$$

$c)$ Use the result from $(b)$ to show that $e ≥ 2$.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What's $f'(x)$?

Comment: compute $f^{'}(x)$

Answer (score 3):

$a)$ $f^´(x)$=$(x-1)\frac1x ≥ = 0$ becouse $x∈ [1,∞)$ then $f$ is nondecreasing

$b)$ $\ln(x)≤x-1$
  iff $x≤  (e)^{x-1}$
  iff $ex≤e^x$

Comment: Those two comments were trying to get Kikkiline to respond and tell what he tried.  But you stepped all over their attempts to help (by giving an answer).  Some would consider that a bit rude.